# Dot Net 6.0 with Azure B2c, Forces login before home page displays

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server dot net 5.0 site with Azure B2C working. I now create a new dot net 6.0 Blazor Server Project in VS 2022 and it sets up B2C. I select my tenant and register a new App Registration.
So far 100% Boiler plate code. I run it and get an error page "Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'..."
I compare my appsettings.json in the working 5.0 site. I add to the 6.0 site:

```
 "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi"
```

The project builds but goes straight to my Azure/B2C login page without displaying the home page of my project. If I login, it now shows the site with me logged in. However if I try to log out it says I have done so successfully but when I navigate to my home page it still shows me logged in.

How do I get it to display the home page so the visitor can choose to log in or not?
How do I get it to log out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. Pull up program.cs and comment out:

```
options.FallbackPolicay = options.DefaultPolicy;
```

Now the site works as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Works in .Net7 as well!